# proxy jboss application with nginx

Tags: nginx, jboss, proxy

Here's the problem: currently one application (on apache) is served with nginx proxy like this:

nginx config for this remote server:

```
    server {
    listen   443;
    server_name  test.example.com;

    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/test.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
    ssl_session_timeout     5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_pass        http://test.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP     192.168.1.10;
    }
}
```

and it works well, the next thing I want to do is to add configuration that would make content from 192.168.1.10:8080/some-context (jboss application on the same server) to be visible at test.example.com/some-context.
The question is how can I achieve it?

PS. I am new to proxy configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, noob question... ;) problem solved - it's as simple as add another location /somecontent to server section (firstly i've added whole another server section - yes, another server section for the same server... and wondered why it's been ignored by nginx ;)